# How can i add more time (months) to an existing timestamp in mongo db using reactjs or js in general

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose

I am building a website and in a component, when the user clicks the respective button I need it to add 1/3/6/12 months to the current date in the database. I can make it update to a pre typed date, but I need it to add more months to that current date, and I couldn't find any way to do that from what I have searched.

This is the code I need the function to happen in.

```
import React, { useContext } from "react";
import { useState } from "react";
import useFetch from "../../hooks/useFetch";
import Footer from "../../components/Footer";
import Navbar from "../../components/Navbar";
import Sidebar from "../../components/Sidebar";
import {
  ContractContainer,
  HeadingContainer,
  TypeH1,
  ActiveUntil,
  MonthlyWrapper,
  MonthlyContainer,
  MonthNumber,
  Price,
  Navbarback,
} from "./userinfoElements";
import { AuthContext } from "../../context/AuthContext";
import moment from "moment";
import axios from "axios";

const Userinfo = () => {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);

  // set state to true ir false
  const toggle = () => {
    setIsOpen(!isOpen);
  };

  const { user } = useContext(AuthContext);
  const { data, loading } = useFetch(`/contracts/${user.contractType}`);

  const updateDate = async () => {
    axios.put(`/activedate/${user.namekey}`, {
      activeUntil: "2026-08-30T22:00:00.000+00:00",
    });
  };

  const dateFormat = moment(user.activeUntil).format("DD/MMMM/yyyy");

  return (
    <>
      <Sidebar isOpen={isOpen} toggle={toggle} />
      {/* navbar for smaller screens*/}
      <Navbar toggle={toggle} />
      <Navbarback /> {/* filling for transparent bacground navbar*/}
      {loading ? (
        "Loading components, please wait"
      ) : (
        <>
          <ContractContainer>
            <HeadingContainer>
              <TypeH1>{data.contractType}</TypeH1>
              <ActiveUntil>Subscription active until {dateFormat}</ActiveUntil>
            </HeadingContainer>
            <MonthlyWrapper>
              <MonthlyContainer>
                <MonthNumber>1 Month</MonthNumber>
                <Price onClick={updateDate}>{data.month1Price}$</Price>
              </MonthlyContainer>
              <MonthlyContainer>
                <MonthNumber>3 Month</MonthNumber>
                <Price onClick={updateDate}>{data.month3Price}$</Price>
              </MonthlyContainer>
              <MonthlyContainer>
                <MonthNumber>6Month</MonthNumber>
                <Price onClick={updateDate}>{data.month6Price}$</Price>
              </MonthlyContainer>
              <MonthlyContainer>
                <MonthNumber>12Month</MonthNumber>
                <Price onClick={updateDate}>{data.month12Price}$</Price>
              </MonthlyContainer>
            </MonthlyWrapper>
          </ContractContainer>
        </>
      )}
      <Footer />
    </>
  );
};

export default Userinfo;
```

This is the part I am having problems with

```
 const updateDate = async () => {
    axios.put(`/activedate/${user.namekey}`, {
      activeUntil: "2026-08-30T22:00:00.000+00:00",
    });
  };
```

Also, if possible, is there any way I can make this   `const dateFormat = moment(user.activeUntil).format("DD/MMMM/yyyy");` get updated when the date changes? Currently, when the date changes, the user has to log out and log back in to get the new updated date.

The mongoose schema I am using.

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  fName: { type: String },
  lName: { type: String },
  namekey: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true,
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  contractType: {
    type: String,
  },
  activeUntil: {
    type: Date,
  },
});

export default mongoose.model("User", UserSchema);
```

Let me know if you need more information, I appreciate any answers.

Comment: Have you checked out [$dateAdd](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v5.0/reference/operator/aggregation/dateAdd/)?

Comment: I resolved this by doing `let newDate = moment(user.activeUntil).add(1, "months");
      dateFormat = newDate.format("DD/MMMM/yyyy");
      axios.put(`/activedate/${user.namekey}`, { activeUntil: newDate`  in the updateDate function but now i can only update once when i click the `<Price>` button and the user has to log out and log back in to update again. If anyone knows how this can be fixed tell me please, even though i am going to search for it myself and going to update this thread when i do.

Comment: This likely will have concurrency issue if you are running the calculation in js layer. Consider doing this in db layer using the $dateAdd method mentioned above.

Comment: i dont know how i could do that in db layer, am using cloud.mongodb.com and i need $dateAdd to happen when i click a button, i am new to react and mongo, sorry i didnt mention earlier

Comment: I asked another question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73473274/database-updates-only-on-the-first-click-of-the-button-with-this-functions-what/73476407#73476407 on another thread that fixed my problems, thnx for the answers.